# Describe an injective function from the real numbers to the real numbers that is not a bijection

Tags: cardinals, real-numbers

Wouldn't the set of real numbers automatically biject the set of real numbers since they are the same set of numbers?

Comment: Also, what's a "total" injection?

Comment: Only injective, I guess

Comment: Consider an exponential function.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: OH, you're saying any FUNCTION from one real numbers to the real numbers...

Comment: Gotchu, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=2^x$. This function is injective because if $2^x=2^y$, then
$$
x= \log_2(2^x)=\log_2(2^y)=y.
$$
However $f$ is not a surjection, because $f(x)>0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.